# Insert a line after pattern match, if only the string does not exists

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Input file

```
Ranges:
- PeakK2:8.8.9
- rover-heal:3.3.1
Arg: V1
change: 1
```

Firstly, check if the string cpu-management exists in the file, if not add it after the rover-heal line like below.

```
Ranges:
- PeakK2:8.8.9
- rover-heal:3.3.1
- cpu-management:1.9.0
Arg: V1
change: 1
```

I came up with a one liner

```
grep -e "cpu-management:" test.yaml || sed -i -e "/rover-heal/- cpu-management:${version}/"  test.yaml
```

where `version` is the environmental variable.

Error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown command: `-'
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : That will substitute line -- `rover-heal`  with `cpu-management`.. Im looking to add it in next line

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This could be done with `awk`, please try following. You can use it as a single code.

```
awk -v val="${version}" '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/cpu-management/){
    found=1
  }
  next
}
/rover/ && found==""{
  print $0 ORS "- cpu-management:" val
  next
}
1
' Input_file  Input_file
```

***OR*** as per Ed sir's suggestion you could do following too use either above OR use following.

```
awk -v val="${version}" '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/cpu-management/){
    found=1
  }
  next
}
{
  print
}
/rover/ && !found{
  print "- cpu-management:" val
}
' Input_file  Input_file
```

For your shown samples output will be as follows:

```
Ranges:
- PeakK2:8.8.9
- rover-heal:3.3.1
- cpu-management:1.9.0
Arg: V1
change: 1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v val="${version}"         ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be treu when 1st time Input_file is being read.
  if($0~/cpu-management/){      ##Checking condition if line contains cpu-management then do following.
    found=1                     ##Setting found to 1 here.
  }
  next                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/rover/ && found==""{           ##Checking if line has rover AND found is NULL then do following.
  print $0 ORS "- cpu-management:" val ##Printing current line ORS with new value.
  next                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                               ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file  Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation.. Found one hiccup though, `${version}` is not getting replaced.
`- cpu-management:${version}`, where `version` is an env variable.

Comment: @voltas, Your welcome. I have added that Logic now, kindly do check it once and let me know if this helps you, cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the detail about cpu-management already existing in the file (that doesn't seem to be a fundamental aspect of the question, and the provided solution already works for that), the classic `sed` solution for the replacement is to use `a`:

```
$ sed "/^- rover-heal/a\\                                         
- cpu-management:${version}
" input-file
Ranges:
- PeakK2:8.8.9
- rover-heal:3.3.1
- cpu-management:
Arg: V1
change: 1
```

If you're using bash, you can simplify the input with:

```
$ sed $'/^- rover-heal/a\\\n'"- cpu-management:$version"$'\n' input-file
Ranges:
- PeakK2:8.8.9
- rover-heal:3.3.1
- cpu-management:
Arg: V1
change: 1
```

Note that some sed allow you to skip the embedded new-line, but not all do.

Comment: @sundeep, no it does not.  The OP already has a mechanism for that which works.  The OP is only having issues with the replacement.

Comment: oh okay, I thought this was entire solution for the given problem, I think adding a clarification will help.. sorry for confusion on my part

Comment: Thank you.. Got to know something new on sed.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `cpu-management` should be checked only after `rover-heal` line:

```
$ version='1.9.0'
$ sed -E '/rover-heal/{$!N; /cpu-management/! s/\n|$/\n- cpu-management:'"${version}"'&/}' ip.txt
Ranges:
- PeakK2:8.8.9
- rover-heal:3.3.1
- cpu-management:1.9.0
Arg: V1
change: 1
```

This was tested on `GNU sed`, syntax might vary for other implementations.

- `/rover-heal/` line to be matched

  - `$!N` get another line, unless `rover-heal` is found on the last line of the input file
  - `/cpu-management/!` check if `cpu-management` is not present

    - `\n|$` match newline or end of line and add details as needed

Use `-i` option for inplace editing.